# access to the php page only with one URL

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a page called settings on my site and I want users to have access only with this url:

```
www.sitename.com/username/settings/
```

I have written this code in the .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/settings$ settings.php?UN=$1[NC,L]
```

But also be accessed with the following addresses:

```
www.sitename.com/settings.php
```

or

```
www.sitename.com/settings.php?UN=username
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /settings\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F] 

RewriteRule ^(.*)/settings/?$ settings.php?UN=$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: And what's the problem now?

Comment: I added the above code . but when type http://localhost:8080/sitename/settings.php or http://localhost:8080/settings.php?UN=username in browser page loaded.   I want  shows error 404 with these addresses